# POSTMAN keeps on sending request no response is getting back.(keeps loading)

Tags: node.js

I have been creating a node backend webtoken. When I tested it through POSTMAN API. It's showing "Sending Request" and no result are returning. The code is given below.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.token;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SEC, (err, user) => {
      if (err){

        
      res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");
      req.user = user;
      next();
      } 
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json("YOu are not authenticated!");
  }
};
const verifyTokenAndAuthorization = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, () => {
    if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.status(403).json("You are not allowed to do that!");
    }
  });
};

module.exports = { verifyToken,verifyTokenAndAuthorization };
```